# use image height to set container height, but sometime script runs before all image loaded

Tags: jquery, image

Im trying to set a container height based on the image inside

I have this code

```
$('.gallery-results__item--image').each(function() {
            var newHeight = 0, $this = $( this );
            newHeight += ($this.children('img').height())+3;
            $this.height( newHeight );
        });
```

which works fine most of the time, but some time it is run before the the image has loaded.

what would be the best way to check the the image has loaded ( has a height)

Comment: give us a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see the rest of the code + images (or use placekitten.com)

Comment: as for your answer, you can make that code wait to run until your images are loaded just put it like this `$('.gallery-results__item--image').on('load', function() { ... });` and you won't need the `.each()` part.

Comment: I WIll try but may not be able to replicate properly in fiddle as image are loaded and this part of a larger function run after images are request via ajax depending on search filters

Answer (score 0):

use *`display:inline-block`* for outer div and  `*display:block*` for  inner div

```css
.div1{
    display:inline-block;
    background:blue;
}
.div2{
    display:block;
    width:40px;
        height:40px;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    
    <div class="div2"> img </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this..
but will not work, as the img position absolute, that is why im getting the image height

Answer (score 0):

Put your code between this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // here JS is executed after all IMAGES are fully loaded
};
```